# python pandas check column contains item from a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, merge, extract

I have two data frames like

```
vid     vbull   
1125    RHSA:2017:3200   
1127    RHSA:2017:3205  
1128    RHSA:2017:3208   
1129    RHSA:2017:3209


kbid    vdesc   
2401    This contains details for RHSA:2017:3205   
2402    This contains details for RHSA:2017:3206   
2403    This contains details forRHSA:2017:3207   
2404    This contains details for RHSA:2017:3208  
2405    This contains details for RHSA:2017:3200
```

Need output from df1,df2 for matching vbull in vdesc like :

```
vid   vbull           kbid   vdesc   
1125  RHSA:2017:3200  2405   This contains details for RHSA:2017:3200   
1127  RHSA:2017:3207  2403  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3207   ...
```

Tried this to get the matched items but not sure how to get the matched item also in the output

```
df2[df2.vdesc.str.contains('|'.join(df1.vbull))]
```

Comment: Are values in `vbull` unique? Check it by `print (df1['vbull'].is_unique)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) for values from `vbull` first:

```
df2['extracted'] = df2.vdesc.str.extract('(' + '|'.join(df1.vbull) + ')', expand=False)
print (df2)
   kbid                                     vdesc       extracted
0  2401  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3205  RHSA:2017:3205
1  2402  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3206             NaN
2  2403  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3207             NaN
3  2404  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3208  RHSA:2017:3208
4  2405  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3200  RHSA:2017:3200
```

Then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df3 = df2[df2['extracted'].notnull()].copy()
print (df3)
   kbid                                     vdesc       extracted
0  2401  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3205  RHSA:2017:3205
3  2404  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3208  RHSA:2017:3208
4  2405  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3200  RHSA:2017:3200
```

And last add values of `vid` by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df3['new'] = df3['extracted'].map(df1.set_index('vbull')['vid'])
print (df3)
   kbid                                     vdesc       extracted   new
0  2401  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3205  RHSA:2017:3205  1127
3  2404  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3208  RHSA:2017:3208  1128
4  2405  This contains details for RHSA:2017:3200  RHSA:2017:3200  1125
```

Comment: Thanks, the values in df1.vbull to be matched with df2.vdesc. Here df2 is not checked.

Comment: oops, bad assign - instaed to `df2` there was `df1`. Sorry :(